# Put a value based on another table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

I have this table above and I need to fill the column "**Basic rate**" which must be based on table below:
[image]

I tried this function to find the quarter and other dates to find a correct place to put a data:

```
=IF(AND(OR(MONTH(C3)=10;MONTH(C3)=11;MONTH(C3)=12);YEAR(C3)=2020);"last";"other")
```

I think there will be a long function to solve this problem. Is there any other way? If not, what formula can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: So, column C in your data is an enrollment flag, not a month. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to count the number of applications per quarter and perform other things too?

Comment: I need to fill the field Basic Rate based on the table in second picture.

Comment: Hint: Build a `VLOOKUP()` formula. The vlookup "table array" section is an `=IF()` formula that will test "relevant expereince" and return the range that the vlookup will work on. In the vlookup "col_index" section put another `=IF()` formula to determine the quarter and return which column to return.

Comment: That second table is a bad data source. It definitely has a source where it was built from. You need access to that source in order to do get your data in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may try this one:**

[image]

**N.B.** *Instead of Two Tables, I've used Data from Two Sheets.*

- Formula in cell AH3:

  ```
  =IF(AND(OR(MONTH(AD3)=10,MONTH(AD3)=11,MONTH(AD3)=12),YEAR(AD3)=2020),VLOOKUP($AF3,Sheet2!$AJ$4:$AL$10,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AF3,Sheet2!$AJ$4:$AL$10,3,FALSE),""))
  ```
- Fill the formula down.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Glad to help you @Bertha Aguilar ,, please keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

For me the following formula worked.
[image]

```
=IF(YEAR(E2)=2020,
    IF(LEFT(F2)="H",
       VLOOKUP(G2,$A$3:$C$5,IF(INT(MONTH(E2)/10),2,3),0),
       VLOOKUP(G2,$A$7:$C$9,IF(INT(MONTH(E2)/10),2,3),0)),
    "")
```